# Consumerism vs. Consumption

Tags: word-meaning, word-difference

Can you guys give me some sentences that indicate a distinction between the two words? I come across several sentences but did not completely grasped the difference.

Comment: Consumption is the process of consuming goods. You buy a loaf of bred to consume it (to eat it). Consumerism is when you're buying things that you don't really need for the sake of buying. Consumption is a process that's considered normal. You buy something and you consume it. Consumerism, on the other hand, has a rather negative connotation as though it were some kind of unhealthy practice. At the very least, it's considered irrational.

Comment: I was about to vote for this as the best answer but realized that it's a comment. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consumption is the process of consuming goods. You buy a loaf of bread to consume it (to eat it). Consumerism is when you're buying things that you don't necessarily need for the sake of buying them. Consumption is a process that's considered normal. It's a technical term for describing the process of using up a resource. You buy something and you use it. That's all there is to it. Consumerism, on the other hand, is a cultural phenomenon and has a rather negative connotation as though it were some kind of unhealthy practice. At the very least, it's considered irrational. It seems to me that shopaholics would probably be the best example of consumerism. They're wasting their time, money and other resources on things, sometimes useless things, that they can easily live without.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can get an idea from these.

- **Consumerism**

Business leaders use  techniques to power  excessive **consumerism**

- **Consumption**

**Consumption** is the value of goods and services bought by people

-referance-

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consumerism